# Android AOSP dev changelog

Tags: android, android-source, changelog

Where can I find a changelog for AOSP?
For example, I have two versions `android-9.0.0_r36` and `android-9.0.0_r35`. Where can I see what has changed between them?

There is this [web-page](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/build-numbers?hl=ru#source-code-tags-and-builds) which has a list of all possible versions.
And there is this [web-page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+log/master?pretty=full&no-merges) that which seems to be a changelog, but I don't understand how to navigate it.

Comment: Not specific to version 9, but here https://mikeng.github.io/aosp.changelog.to/index.html you can find changelogs